# How to run Julia through REPL on atom

Tags: github, julia, atom-editor

I want to run Julia code saved from GitHub through my REPL but this does not seem to work. I have tried even a simple file that has the code `println("hello)` but it just seems to show me it is running on the lower left without actually outputting anything on my REPL. This is how my screen looks. [image]

Here are the outputs for vscode:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your problem - there is output in your REPL at the bottom?

In Juno, you can run code in two ways:

1. Using the REPL provided at the bottom - this is what you seemingly did in your screenshot, just typing something into the REPL and pressing Enter will print the results to the REPL
2. By evaluating code in the editor window at the top. This might be what you're trying to do, and it works by just pressing `Ctrl+Enter` when your cursor is on the line/block (loop, function...) you want to run, or `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` to run the whole file. Note that to do this, your file has to be a `*.jl` file, so it wouldn't work for the "untitled" file you have open in your screenshot.

Documentation can be found [here](http://docs.junolab.org/stable/man/basic_usage/#Inline-Evaluation-1).

I should also note that the development focus of the Juno team has shifted to the VSCode Julia extension, as Atom isn't being actively developed anymore since Microsoft acquired GitHub. It's still perfectly usable and gets bugfixes, but any major new features are likely to be available on VSCode only.

Comment: Okay I have switched to VSCode. I have downloaded a zipfile and uploaded it onto my vscode application and everything is saved as blank.jl. I clicked alt enter to run the whole page but I do not see anything spitting out in my terminal. I will update the question above

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using a Mac. You can run individual lines in Atom Juno with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. If you use the `|> run` button, it runs the file selected in the project pane, not necessarily the editor pane you are looking at.

It is also <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> for VSCode on the Mac.